# How can I add grid lines to a print composition using pyqgis?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer, grids-graticules

I'm writing a qgis plugin to create an image in the print composer of the current map.  I can get the map rendered in the proper place with a frame of the right width, and I can get grid annotations rendered in the proper places and orientation, but I can't get the actual grid lines to render.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
def createImage(self):
    # Initialize the composition object.
    mapRenderer = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()
    composition = QgsComposition(mapRenderer)
    composition.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)
    composition.setPaperSize(483, 330)
    composition.setPrintResolution(300)

    # Initialize the map object.  Allow a top margin of 10mm, a bottom
    # margin of 50mm, a left margin of 10mm, and a right margin of 10mm.
    mapOriginXMm = 10
    mapOriginYMm = 10
    mapWidthMm = 483 - 10 -10
    mapHeightMm = 330 - 10 - 50
    composerMap = QgsComposerMap(composition, \
                                     mapOriginXMm, \
                                     mapOriginYMm, \
                                     mapWidthMm, \
                                     mapHeightMm)
    composition.addItem(composerMap)

    # Create the frame around the map.
    composerMap.setFrameEnabled(1)
    pen = QPen()
    pen.setWidth(0.2)
    pen.setJoinStyle(Qt.MiterJoin)
    composerMap.setPen(pen)

    # Initialize the image object.
    dpi = 300
    dpmm = dpi / 25.4
    paperWidthPixels = int(dpmm * composition.paperWidth())
    paperHeightPixels = int(dpmm * composition.paperHeight())
    image = QImage(QSize(paperWidthPixels, paperHeightPixels), \
                       QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    image.setDotsPerMeterX(dpmm * 1000)
    image.setDotsPerMeterY(dpmm * 1000)
    image.fill(0)

    # Create the map grid.
    composerMap.setGridEnabled(True)
    composerMap.setGridIntervalX(500)
    composerMap.setGridIntervalY(500)
    composerMap.setShowGridAnnotation(True)
    composerMap.setGridAnnotationPrecision(0)
    composerMap.setGridStyle(QgsComposerMap.Solid)

    # Top
    composerMap.setGridAnnotationPosition(QgsComposerMap.OutsideMapFrame, \
                                              QgsComposerMap.Top)
    composerMap.setGridAnnotationDirection(QgsComposerMap.Horizontal, \
                                               QgsComposerMap.Top)
    # Bottom
    composerMap.setGridAnnotationPosition(QgsComposerMap.OutsideMapFrame, \
                                              QgsComposerMap.Bottom)
    composerMap.setGridAnnotationDirection(QgsComposerMap.Horizontal, \
                                               QgsComposerMap.Bottom)

    # Left
    composerMap.setGridAnnotationPosition(QgsComposerMap.OutsideMapFrame, \
                                              QgsComposerMap.Left)
    composerMap.setGridAnnotationDirection(QgsComposerMap.Vertical, \
                                               QgsComposerMap.Left)

    # Right
    composerMap.setGridAnnotationPosition(QgsComposerMap.OutsideMapFrame, \
                                              QgsComposerMap.Right)
    composerMap.setGridAnnotationDirection(QgsComposerMap.Vertical, \
                                               QgsComposerMap.Right)

    composerMap.setAnnotationFrameDistance(1)
    composerMap.setGridPenWidth(5.0)
    composerMap.setGridPenColor(QColor(0, 0, 0))
    composerMap.setAnnotationFontColor(QColor(0, 0, 0))
    composerMap.setGridBlendMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_DestinationOver)

    # Do the rendering.
    imagePainter = QPainter(image)
    paperRectMm = QRectF(0, \
                             0, \
                             composition.paperWidth(), \
                             composition.paperHeight())
    paperRectPixels = QRectF(0, 0, paperWidthPixels, paperHeightPixels)
    composition.render(imagePainter, paperRectPixels, paperRectMm)
    imagePainter.end()

    image.save("/opt/tmpPhotos/test.tif", "tif")
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon the solution.  Instead of

```
composition.addItem(composerMap)
```

the code should read

```
composition.addComposerMap(composerMap)
```